# how to make a series of links in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepiont

I am creating a wiki repository and for a specific section I would like to have a series. In the starting page of this series I would like to have a way to direct me to part 2 of the series, and similarly in part 2 I would like part 2 to be able to direct me back to  part 1 but also to part 3 etc. I apologize if this seems unclear an example of my vision is this following [SuperBowl1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_I) link in which on the right hand side under all the stats there is an arrow that if clicked will direct you to the wiki page of [SuperbBowl2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_II).

Comment: Are you asking how to insert a link in a SharePoint Wiki page?

Answer (score 2):

You can create the links as Wiki Page links by typing them between a set of sqare brackets, or you can insert links via the ribbon command.

You'll need to do that on every page, manually linking to the desired pages.